# Structure Map - Registering wrapper of an old interface for a new interface

Tags: c#, vb.net, structuremap

Morning,

in the codebase i'm maintaining there is an old interface. Let's call it IFoo. It pretty much became obsolete and replaced with the Interface INewFoo with a change a few weeks ago, but for backwards-compatibility purposes, i wrote a wrapper class which implements INewFoo and takes an IFoo in the constructor.

To clarify, consider the following code.

```
    Public Interface IFoo
      Sub DoStuff()
    End Interface

    Public Interface INewFoo
      Sub DoPrettyMuchTheSameStuff()
    End Interface

    Public Class FooToNewFooWrapper
      Implements INewFoo

      Private _foo As IFoo
      Public Sub New(foo As IFoo)
        _foo = foo
      End Sub

      Public Sub DoPrettyMuchTheSameStuff() Implements INewFoo.DoPrettyMuchTheSameStuff
        _foo.DoStuff()
      End Sub
    End Class
```

For both interfaces, the implementations are loaded by scanning a few assemblies with StructureMap.

Now, let's get to the bad things. Most implementations for the old interface were put into forms for reason i can neither understand nor change. Because those tend to be displayed and disposed, i have to create a new instance every time i use ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances(Of IFoo). Thats still no problem, but i'd like to register a INewFoo-Wrapper for each registered implementation of IFoo, so that i can just use ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances(of INewFoo) and get all implementations of IFoo AND INewFoo.

I can't iterate through the implementations of IFoo and register a wrapper for each one because as far as i can see, you can just register those with instances.

**Wrong code below:**

```
  ObjectFactory.Configure(Sub(config)
                            config.Scan(Sub(scan)
                                          For Each ass In assemblies
                                            scan.Assembly(ass)
                                          Next
                                          scan.AddAllTypesOf(Of IFoo)()
                                        End Sub)
                          End Sub)

Dim oldImplementations = ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances(Of IFoo)()

  ObjectFactory.Configure(Sub(config)
                            For Each implementation In oldImplementations
                              Dim notIterated = implementation
                              config.For(Of INewFoo).Add(Function(x) New FooToNewFooWrapper(notIterated))
                            Next
                          End Sub)
```

My question is: Is it possible to register a wrapper for each implementation of IFoo which always creates a new instance of the implementation before creating a new instance of the wrapper?

Answers in C# and Vb.net are equally welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried implementing a custom registration convention to carry out your specific requirement? Custom registration conventions allow very flexible scanning and registering

```
[CLSCompliant(false)]
public class MyRegistration : IRegistrationConvention
/// <inheritdoc />
    public void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
    {           

        Type interfaceType = type.GetInterface(typeof(IFoo).Name);
        if (interfaceType == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        registry.AddType(interfaceType, type, type.Name);

        // Do your stuff with INewFoo

    }
}
```

Configure structure map to use your scanner:

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(item =>
            {
                item.Scan(
                    x =>
                    {
                        x.AssembliesFromPath("c:\wheremyassemblyis.dll");
                        x.With(new MyRegistration());
                    });
            });
```

Comment: It took a little longer for me to try it out, but with a few workarounds, i managed to make it happen.